# Ordering a drop down alphabetically angular

Tags: angular, sorting

```
            <div class="form-group" *jhiHasAnyAuthority="['ROLE_ADMIN']">
                <label class="form-control-label" jhiTranslate="ManagementApp.project.lab" for="field_leader">Add Lab</label>
                <select class="form-control" id="field_lab" name="lab">
                    <option [ngValue]="null"></option>
                    <option *ngFor="let lab of labs;" (click)="addLab(lab)">{{lab.labCode}}</option>
                </select>
            </div>
```

I am maintaining some angular code with zero prior experience.

I am trying to create an alphabetically sorted dropdown. I tried to imitate this [load drop down values alphabetic order angular 6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55842594/load-drop-down-values-alphabetic-order-angular-6) , but without success.

I have tried `"let lab of labs| orderBy: 'lab.labCode';"`

and `"let lab of labs.sort();"` as labs has a sort function already.

The sort function prototype is `sort(compareFn?: (a: T, b: T) => number): this;` with:

> Sorts an array.
>         * @param compareFn The name of the function used to determine the order of the elements. If omitted, the elements are sorted in
>   ascending, ASCII character order.

The lab as you can see has a labCode (string), which needs to be used for the sorting.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

----EDITS---------
Contents of labs array:
[image]

Comment: why don't you order labs array in OnInit() ?

Comment: Because my thinking was, "locate where this happens, then modify it to do what I want", I guess. I remind you, that I have 0 experience in this. Could you elaborate with some more detail?

Comment: Could you please show the content of labs array

Comment: Please check edits section. I hope this is what you meant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below code can be added in **component's ngOnInit() or in your API call success** to sort alphabetically

**labs.sort((a, b) => a.labCode.localeCompare(b.labCode));**

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

There is no örderBy pipe in higher versions of angular. You have to write a pipe as given in the example - https://medium.com/@mohammad.nicoll/sort-pipe-in-angular-6-7-f22475cc4054 and apply the same.

Answer (score 0):

You can sort you array in `ngOnInit()`

```
 sorted : []
 ngOnInit(): void {

    this.sorted = labs.sort((a, b) => a.labCode> b.labCode? 1 : -1);
  }
```

in your html use sorted  insted of labs